# Instanciar un objeto en Java

Tags: java

Quisiera poder probar los métodos de mi clase pero, como no sé crear una instancia de la misma no tengo forma de realizar dichas pruebas.

Os pongo los dos archivos a ver si me podéis echar una mano. Mil gracias.

```
package inputs;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsoleInput {

    // VARIABLES
    String string;

    char letter;
    boolean condition = false;


    private final Scanner keyboard;

    public ConsoleInput(Scanner keyboard) {
        this.keyboard = keyboard;
    }
    private void cleanInput() {
        keyboard.nextLine();
    }


    public char readChar() {
        // Retorna un carácter introducido por el usuario.
        // Si este introduc más de uno, se le vuelve a solicitar.

        do { // Pide una cadena de texto hasta que solo se introduzca un caracter.
            string = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (string.length() != 1) {
                System.out.println("No has introducido un carácter válido. Vuelve a introducirlo. ");
            }
        } while (string.length() != 1);

        letter = string.charAt(0);

        return letter;
    }
}
```

```
package inputs;

import inputs.ConsoleInput.*;

public class Pruebas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsoleInput inputs = new ConsoleInput(Scanner Keyboard);
    }

}
```

Donde he puesto Scanner Keyboard, creo que tengo que poner otra cosa (en el segundo código), pero no idea.

Gracias.

Comment: En el segundo código deberías de crear un objeto, o una instancia de `Scanner` y pasarle ese objeto por parametro al constructor de `ConsoleInput`. Y te recomendaria que si no sabes POO, te documentes sobre ello antes de empezar a programar.

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar a ver si consigo hacerlo.

Sí sé algo de POO, el problema es que eso es para una actividad en java para el grado superior de programación y nos han enviado un ejercicio con métodos cuando todavía no los hemos dados, así que estoy bastante confuso con la actividad.

Gracias!

Comment: Si quieres obtener mejor ayuda indica la descripción de la practica, es decir, lo que debes de hacer, junto al código. Y así sabría decirte mejor.

Comment: Gracias, con eso me bastó para poder hacer el ejercicio.